# Geoserver set the Geowebcache Max Cache Level

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

We are wanting to display image cache for the entire of England to a level of 1:3000 (level **10** in our gridset). Beyond that we want to call upon the standard WMS service, feeding dynamically from the database/file store. The Layer is being published to level **19**.

In **Geoserver 2.4.0** any layer that has a "Cached Zoom Level" set to a particular level (i.e level 10) will dynamically render a WMS service beyond that level. In **geoserver 2.6.0** this no longer happens and we receive an error from geowebcache:

400: Null (network response in chrome - 400:Bad Request)

I understand that this is beyond the level of cache available but why is geowebcache no longer going directly to the Layer WMS like before? Is it possible an error in the geowebcache.xml could cause this?

I have tried this test on the Geoserver sample layers, as well as my own to highlight the fact that this is not an independent issue.